# Is this preloader working? It's not being used to show status, just speed up possible image loading for later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, preloader

I've been reading up on the best way to handle images for a website (which cycles through images to display when a user clicks an element) and it seems a preloader is advantageous.

Given you can take out the preloader and the current setup will simply insert image1 into the div anyway from the array, is the preloader working by including all potential HTML requests at the start, therefore reducing potential loading time later, or is this a useless implementation as it's written?

Should I actually be taking the images from the `imageObj` in the `.append(...)` ?

-NOTE - I'm aware that I'm only actually allowing the calling to image1 as it is, but this is just a practise.

## HTML

```
<body>
    <a href='#' id="image1">
    Click for image 1
    </a>
    <hr/>
    <a href='#' id="image2">
    Click for image 2
    </a>
    <hr/>
    <a href='#' id="image3">
    Click for image 3
    </a>
    <hr/>
    <a href='#' id="image4">
    Click for image 4
    </a>
    <div id="image">
    </div>
</body>
```

## JavaScript/jQuery

```
// JavaScript Document

function preloader() 
{
    var i = 0;

    imageObj = new Image();

    images = new Array();
    images[0]="images/image1.jpg"
    images[1]="images/image2.jpg"
    images[2]="images/image3.jpg"
    images[3]="images/image4.jpg"

    for(i=0; i<=3; i++) 
    {
        imageObj.src=images[i];
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    preloader();

    $('#image1').click(function(){
        alert("Handler for #image1 .click() called.");
        $('#image').append('<img id="theImg" src=' + images[0] + ' />');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect of this code is to just "touch" each possible image so it gets loaded into your cache but not your DOM if that makes sense.

> Should I actually be taking the images from the imageObj in the .append(...) ?

No, that part is just to force the get to preload the image into your browser cache. Notice how it is overwritten almost immediately in the loop.

If you want blistering load speeds then also consider having your images come from multiple subdomains or a CDN.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point I hadn't considered that. Great thanks very much! I'll stick this one in the 'useful' library then. :)

Thanks for the pointer to multiple subdomains/ CDNs. That's appreciated.